# What is internal storage on Android?

Tags: android, local-storage, internal

i am new in android,so i have some html pages that contain some events information that i want to save inside the project so the user dont have to go online to view them. i have read solutions online that i can put them i assets folder. 
but, then i read that assets is read only so i cant update my html page if i want to update them with new events information. 
There's one sollution i found online, by putting those pages on internal storage, the question is, where is the internal storage on my project? should i make a new folder on my project and put those pages there? is there any solutions so that i dont have to put may pages into assets folder?

Comment: internal storage is like the harddisk on your computer

Comment: @josepnabu give this resource a try, this is all you need to know when it comes to storage options in android. [url](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Yeah, its means to put your files on the device memory or external SDCard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Internal Storage:** Store *private* data on the device memory.

If you want something private inside your app, store it here. If you store anything in the External Storage every app can access it.

Read the docs....

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: You're not answering the question. The question is how to put data on internal storage on compile/install time.

Comment: @Seltymar no, the question was, from the title "What is internal storage on Android?" and "where is the internal storage on my project". The author was clueless about anything, so the best answer here was a brief explanation and a doc link. Furthermore he obviously didn't spend any time on searching a bit on Google.

Comment: I agree, you answered the first question but no the 3 others which can be translate (from his explanation) on what I said in the comment above. I think this is an interesting question and there is not a lot of source which explain how to do it cleanly.